# Showing a polynomial ring is Noetherian and has Krull dimension 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $m\in \mathbb N$ and let $F$ be a field. Then
$$A = \{a_0 + a_mx^m + \dots + a_nx^n: a_i \in F, n\ge m\} \subseteq F[x]$$
is a subring of $F[x]$. I need to show it is a Noetherian ring and has Krull dimension 1.

I tried showing that $A$ is isomorphic to a quotient ring of $F[x]$, but I couldn't find an appropriate epimorphism from $F[x]$ to $A$. I believe it's isomorphic to a quotient module of $F[x]$ by the (module) epimorphism $a_0 + \dots + a_n x^n \mapsto a_0 + a_mx^m + \dots + a_nx^n$, but I don't think it helps as I need to show it's a Noetherian ring.

Comment: Maybe I am reading the set wrong, but do you mean that $A$ is the set of polynomials with constant term (can be zero) and then a sum starting with $m$ as least power of $x$ and higher order terms?

Comment: @RenéBruin Yes. My last epimorphism shows that $A$ is isomorphic to a quotient module of $F[x]$, so $A$ is a nNoetherian module over $F$ by Hilbert’s basis theorem.  Therefore if $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \dots$ are ideals then they are also sub modules of $A$, therefore the chain terminates and $A$ is also a Noetherian ring. I still can’t show that it has Krull dimension 1. I think it might have to do with the correspondence theorem but don’t see how to apply it

Comment: The epimorphism you have defined is an epimorphism of modules over $F$. $F[x]$ is not a Noetherian module over $F$, it is only Noetherian over itself. So there is no reason why the quotient should be a Noetherian module over $F$.

Comment: @Mark right, thanks (also for the answer)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that $F[x]$ is integral over $A$. From the going up theorem it follows that the two rings have the same dimension. Clearly, $F[x]$ has dimension $1$.

Now look at the algebra $F[x^m]\subseteq A$. This is a finitely generated algebra over $F$, and so a Noetherian algebra by Hilbert's basis theorem. $F[x]$ is a finitely generated module over $F[x^m]$ (for example because $x$ is integral over $F[x^m]$), and so a Noetherian module over $F[x^m]$. If so, the submodule $A$ is finitely generated over $F[x^m]$. So let $f_1,...,f_r\in A$ such that:

$A=F[x^m]f_1+F[x^m]f_2+...+F[x^m]f_r$

Then clearly $A=F[x^m, f_1,...,f_r]$. So $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over $F$, and hence a Noetherian ring.